# Necessary conditions for $f$ such that $f(X)$ has an absolutely continuous distribution when $X$ has one

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, absolute-continuity

I was wondering if anyone could give me a reference for necessary conditions for a function $f$ such that $f(X)$ has an absolutely continuous distribution when $X$ has one.